# How to call a pointer to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, unique-ptr

Normally, I'd call this function pointer using syntax like the following.

```
using func_ptr = void (*)();

// ...

(*func_ptr)();
```

When wrapping a function pointer in a unique_ptr ...

```
std::unique_ptr<func_ptr> fp;

fp = std::make_unique<func_ptr>((func_ptr) dlsym(handle, "somefunc"));
```

... how does one call a pointer to a function pointer? I tried ...

```
(**fp)();
```

to no avail.

Comment: @SPlatten no the syntax of `using` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Timo, you cannot call a function pointer when it doesn't point to anything.  Looking at the other code the last line looks like it should be (*fp)();

Comment: Since c++11 using can be used to alias type names. 
And of course you can call a function pointer that points no where, it will probably crash, but you can do it.

Comment: @SPlatten you said the `using` statement is wrong, but it isn't. The fact that OP tries to dereference a type alias is the error.

Comment: I guess I hadn't considered the case of dynamically loaded libraries. Though it seems like you would want to supply a meaningful Deleter for your unique_ptr.

Comment: Just `(*fp)();` seems to have worked for me. Same as with a regular non-`unique_ptr` pointer.

Comment: First of all you overcomplicated things - `func_ptr()` is sufficient. Then you can use `(*fp)()`

Comment: I can't find anything that describes how `unique_ptr` are expected to handle function pointers. I would expect the default deleter to try to `delete` the function pointer which isn't allowed. I'm not sure how or why this compiles.

Comment: @Slava - Only reason I was wrapping a function pointer in a unique_ptr was to eventually store them in a vector. Sounds like you're saying I can leave unique_ptr out and store func_ptr? And unique_ptr just seemed easier to deal with.

Comment: `(**fp)();` works perfectly fine for me. But you could also just store the function pointer.

Comment: Ok, apparently it does work. I tried (**fp)(); again but in a local scope and it's fine. I have something else going on and this is not my problem. Though ... not sure what to do with this question now.

Comment: Storing a function pointer in a `std::unique_ptr` seem really strange... Do you really need to delete it?

Comment: @Slava - I mostly understand the move semantics going on, which is what I think my issue is. Right now I'm reconsidering my reasoning for needing a unique_ptr. As far as invoking goes, I'm reading up on that point now. I think what I don't understand are the comments about deleting it.

Comment: @Ender `std::unique_ptr` by default manages dynamically allocated objects, which created using `operator new` either directly or indirectly through `std::make_unique` so it calls `delete` when destroyed. As your function pointers are not created by new you will have UB. But you can use `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleter if you need to call something to c lean them up. But I believe `dlsym()` objects do not need cleanup so your reason to use unique_ptr is bogus.

Comment: @Ender for example it would be a good idea to store shared library handle in `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleter that calls `dlclose()`. Looks like you need to learn how to use smart pointers and what they are for.

Comment: Is the use of unique_ptr's here bad practice ... http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/48TbqMoL/

Comment: "How to call a pointer to a function pointer?" -> "How to call a function *through* (or via) a function pointer?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When wrapping a function pointer in a unique_ptr ...

This is a problem, since this doesn't have sense. Smart pointers are for things which have finite well defined lifetime. Things which you can create and destroy. Note that in `C` and `C++` functions have infinitive life time, ergo there is no point to use smart pointers to functions.

Now since you are using `dlsym` so dynamic library are involved (this is outside of standard). You may think: "yes my function has finite life time, since it is loaded from dll, so it is time for smart pointer".

Idea may seam good, but note that resource for management here is not a a function, but library itself. You are openning dll by `dlopen` and close it with `dlclose`. So the handle to library should be managed by smart pointer! This means that smart pointer to function still is not a good choice.

A proper solution is to use `boost::dll` (header only library), which does this for you in very nice way.

If you want do it your self you need:

- class which will manage dll lifetime (load time) - may be managed by `std::shared_ptr`
- classes which will represent functions in dll. They may hold `shared_ptr` to dll class, to ensure that dll is loaded as long as there is any class holding pointer to function in that dll.